# How to delay MacBook Pro sleeping

Tags: macbook-pro

I need to know how to delay the automatic sleep on the Macbook Pro. It sleeps too early.

If I leave it for one minute it sleeps. I tried the view options but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in System Preferences -> Energy Saver. You may need an admin password to change settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your Mac on forever when you need to without digging into settings if you download the Mac app [Caffeine](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caffeine/id411246225?mt=12).

Alternatively, you can use OS X's built-in command line tool [`caffeinate`](https://dssw.co.uk/reference/caffeinate.html) to keep your Mac awake for longer periods.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using a tool called "Should I Sleep" for several years now. It sits in your menu bar and allows you to set all kinds of 'sensors' to determine if or not the computer is 'allowed to go to sleep'.

Examples of these sensors are "is there sound?" "Is there a person sitting at the computer?" "Has the download already finished?" Etc. I believe some sensors are free, others are not.

Have a look [at the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/should-i-sleep/id560851219) for this application.

*Note: I'm just a user, not the developer, and I gain in no way by you opting for this software. Just looking to help.*